# how to Compare two tables that contain millions of entries but different in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. One contains three columns and the second contains more, and I want the corresponding values ​​between the two tables to be the corresponding values ​​of the table containing the most columns.

Note that I experimented with this code but the values ​​were null
Thanks.

```sql
SELECT 
plate_lable.numbers, 
plate_lable.governorate, 
plate_lable.usage,
TO_CHAR(NULL) "chassis",
TO_CHAR(NULL) "brand",
TO_CHAR(NULL) "vehicle_production_year",
TO_CHAR(NULL) "DATES",
TO_CHAR(NULL) "use_case"
FROM  
plate_lable 

INTERSECT

SELECT 
t_registered_unit.numbers AS numbers,
t_registered_unit.governorate AS governorate,
t_registered_unit.usage AS usage,
t_registered_unit.chassis as chassis,
t_registered_unit.brand as brand,
t_registered_unit.vehicle_production_year as vehicle_production_year,
TO_CHAR(CAST(t_registered_unit.CREATED AS DATE), 'YYYY\MM\dd') AS DATES,
t_registered_unit.use_case as use_case
FROM
t_registered_unit
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: That's called a `join` :-)

Comment: The INTERSECT operator produces the set of records which **exist in both tables**. So expanding the projection `plate_lable` with null columns won't match anything in `t_registered_unit`..

Comment: When using normal connectivity methods, there is no Quirky output until after a long time and the database is disconnected

Comment: There are a few ways to interpret your question, so we definitely need you to edit your question and provide a few rows of sample data from each table, and desired results of your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t1.numbers, 
  t1.governorate, 
  t1.usage,
  t2.chassis as chassis,
  t2.brand as brand,
  t2.vehicle_production_year as vehicle_production_year,
  TO_CHAR(CAST(t2.CREATED AS DATE), 'YYYY\MM\dd') AS DATES,
  t2.use_case as use_case

FROM  
  plate_lable                  t1
  inner join t_registered_unit t2
ON
  t1.numbers      = t2.numbers     and
  t1.governorate  = t2.governorate and
  t1.usage        = t2.usage ;
```

Comment: When using normal connectivity methods, there is no Quirky output until after a long time and the database is disconnected